# add marker that has position value above slider(or rangeslider)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-slider

How can I add marker (or checker) above slider?
Also, I need information about the position value of the marker on slider.

[image]

how could add red triangle on slider?

Comment: You can try with `Stack` widget

Comment: How could I get position information about marker?

Comment: you can try with layoutBuilder at the top level